# GoJS full image download not just the section in the viewport

Tags: javascript, angular, image, gojs

I am trying to download the image as blob. But the problem is that only the image section is getting downloaded that is in the viewport. I want the entire image to get downloaded.

Here is the function that I am using:

```
downloadER() {
    this.diagram.rebuildParts();
    const downloadCallback = (blob: any): void => {
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        var imageDataUrl = reader.result;
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = imageDataUrl; // For getting the height and width
        let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'b2');
        var position = 0;
        pdf.setFontSize(20);
        pdf.text(breadcrumb, 250, 20, 'center');
        pdf.addImage(imageDataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 25, position, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
        pdf.save(pdfTitle + ".pdf");
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
    let blob = this.diagram.makeImageData({ background: "white", returnType: "blob", callback: <any>downloadCallback});
  }
```

How can I download the full image.

Answer (score 0):

add `{ scale: 1 }` to your options and it will use the entire document bounds instead of just what's in the viewport.